# Matrix vector multiplication in $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$?

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, computational-complexity

Let $\phi_{ij}(x, y) = \psi_i(x) \psi_j(y)$ and $1 \le i, j \le n$
Let
$$M_{ij, kl} = \sum_{\alpha, \beta} w_{\alpha} w_{\beta}\phi_{ij}(x_\alpha, x_\beta)  \phi_{kl}(x_\alpha, x_\beta)G(x_\alpha, x_\beta)$$
where $G$ is a weight function, $w_1,...,w_n$ are weights and $x_1,...,x_n$ are points.
How can one compute $y = Mu$ in $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$?

We can map the indices of $y$ to a tensor and then we can write the elements of $y$ as follows:
$$y_{i,j} = \sum_{k, l} M_{ij, kl} \ u_{k, l}$$
$$ = \sum_{k, l} [\sum_{\alpha, \beta} w_{\alpha} w_{\beta}\ \psi_{i}(x_\alpha)\ \psi_{j} (x_\beta)\  \psi_k (x_\alpha)\ \psi_{l} (x_\beta) G(x_\alpha, x_\beta)]\ u_{k, l}$$
If there weren't the weight function we could split the sum into the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ part but I don't see how that would help either. Naively we can compute $y$ in $\mathcal{O}(n^4)$, has anyone an idea how we can do it in $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$?

Comment: Why is $x$ going up and down in indices in this question? Sometimes it has only one, and sometimes it has two.

Comment: @PaulSinclair my bad, I used $x$ twice, once as the quadrature points and once as the vector $M$ gets multiplied by, I changed it.

Comment: $u$ is in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$

Comment: Your naive approach calculates $y_{i,j}$ in $O(n^4)$. The calculation of $y = Mu$ is in $O(n^6)$.  And unless the $\phi$ or $\psi$ (you change symbols midstream) are particularly well-behaved, there is no way that is going down to $O(n^3)$. Are you needing to calculate $y$ for one particular $u$, or for many $u$?

Comment: The $\phi_{ij}$ are a basis set on a domain $\Omega$. And the sum comes from numerical integration but I don't see how that helps. Well yes if we go with the defintion of $M$ but if $M$ is given then it is $\mathcal{O}(n^4)$.

Comment: $M$ has symmetries that could be exploited: $M_{ij,kl} = M_{kl,ij} = M_{il,kj} = M_{kj,il}$, but that only divides it by $4$, not $n$. Do you have any additional information about $G$ that could be useful? Why do you have a weight function and then separate weights anyway?

Comment: So if $G$ weren't there, we could write $M$ as $(A^T W \otimes A^T W)(A\otimes A)$ where $W_{ii} = w_{i}$ and $0$ else and $A_{ij} = \psi_i (x_j)$ ($A$ and $W$ are $n \times n$ matrix). So $Mu = (A^T W \otimes A^T W)(A\otimes A)u $ and if I'm not wrong $(A\otimes A)u = \mathrm{flatten}(A(AU)^T)$ where $U_{ij} = u_{i+(j-1)n}$ and that can be done in $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$

Comment: If $w_\alpha w_\beta$ is enough to meet your weighting needs, yes.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with numerical integration, this is gonna be used to compute a numerical solution to the equations of linear elasticity but I don't see a way with $G$ if it cannot be decomposed into two parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, exchange order of summation, and sum with respect to $k,l$:
$$
a_{\alpha,\beta}:=\sum_{k}\psi_k (x_\alpha)\ \left(\sum_l \psi_{l} (x_\beta)\ u_{k, l}\right),
$$
this are two products of $n\times n$ matrices, so $O(n^3)$ operations are needed to compute the entries $a$. Then compute
$$
b_{\alpha,\beta}:=w_{\alpha} w_{\beta}G(x_\alpha, x_\beta)a_{\alpha,\beta},
$$
which are $3n^2$ multiplications.
Then compute
$$
\sum_\alpha \left( \sum_{\beta} b_{\alpha,\beta}\psi_j (x_\beta) \right)\psi_i (x_\alpha)
$$
again two matrix multiplications of $O(n^3)$.